# How to remove same named objects from a JSON structure, but with a non uniform pattern in structure?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a json structure, that is a bit odd, this is returned from a remote device, and I have to accept it as is.  For example...

```
{"_":"e6a7f749","4321013c":{"_":"5d839a60"},"67ea44a0":{"_":"ec7500f9"},"6bea5f08":{"_":"ecdaead4"},"1e92311e":{"_":"5348dab3"}}
```

I need to remove the '_' key-value pairs, but retain everything else, such that...

```
{"4321013c":,"67ea44a0":,"6bea5f08":,"1e92311e":,}
```

As you can see, this leaves just some 'keys', from the original structure.  I then want to convert the 'keys' to a simple array of values.  Such...

```
["4321013c","67ea44a0","6bea5f08","1e92311e"]
```

All this done in node.js (JavaScript) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I am not sure if I fully understood the question though.

But here I traverse the object, an gather up all the keys and values into another, flattened object. Then finally, I run Object.keys on that and remove any "_" values.

```
const obj = {
  "_":"e6a7f749",
  "4321013c":{"_":"5d839a60"},
  "67ea44a0":{"_":"ec7500f9"},
  "6bea5f08":{"_":"ecdaead4"},
  "1e92311e":{"_":"5348dab3"}
  };


const collectValues = (root) => {
    return Object.keys(root).reduce((map, key) => {
      const value = root[key];
      if (typeof value === 'string') {
        map = {
          ...map, 
          [key]: true, 
          [value]: true
        };
      } else {
        const nestedValues = collectValues(root[key]);
        map = {
          ...map, 
          ...nestedValues, 
          [key]: true
        };
      }
      return map;
    }, {});
}

const uniqueArray = Object.keys(collectValues(obj)).filter(v => v !== '_');

console.log(uniqueArray);
```